# Xamarin.Forms persistent system clock

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am struggling to find a way for my scheduling app to account for the user changing the system time. I appreciate that if the user changes the time zone I can see that, but if they make a change to the actual clock then it sends everything out.

To make it more awkward there might be several hours between use of my app in which the phone might be switched off, and it will have no connectivity for most of the time.

I was hoping there was a persistent clock that unaffected by the user changing the time, or that there was a way (in xamarin.forms) of catching an event or a message of the user changes the time.

Thanks in advance of your help

AJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's [Location](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Locations.Location/), iOS [CLLocation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.CoreLocation.CLLocation/) and Mac [CLLocation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoMac.CoreLocation.CLLocation/) includes the UTC of timefix (doesn't have to be GPS, just cell tower is enough). In theory user can operate rogue bluetooth GPS provider, fake software GPS provider with rooting or jailbreaking, but unless you can move the time collection & calculation logic to your own server instead of user's controlled device, relying on location provider would be the least effort.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm deffo going to look into that. I'm still interested in more solutions as well, as there is a high possibility that many users will be out of cell range for an extended period of time.

AJ

Comment: Will they be out of GPS too (like inside building)? If the device is supposed to operate without any connectivity whatsoever, not even iOS have tamper-proof clock hardware, so either change the flow since user's device is inherently untrusted, or add extended tamper proof RTC hardware. Maybe repurpose cheap Android/Pi as time server & hotspot, put it under locked box along huge powerbank & power-only USB cable jutting out, require your user to carry it around. And no, I'm not joking, that's the only way

Comment: [Samsung's Knox](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/samsung_android_with_knox_1.x/2014-04-22/finding/V-48277) solution was to disable manual time changes through MDM policy, and require regular synchronization. So even if you provide your users with [Knox](https://www.samsungknox.com/en/knox-supported-devices/my-knox) compatible devices, you'll still need a connection once a day.

Comment: You guys are very knowledgeable, thank you. They will be out of GPS a lot of the time (at sea) but actually I might be able to get something from that. I'm going to have a good play. Thanks.

Comment: Uh, they'll still have GPS at sea, unless they are in a submarine or underwater lab